# Is $\sum_{n\ge0}\frac1{2^{2^n}}$ rational?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, rationality-testing

How might I determine whether $\sum_{n\ge0}\frac1{2^{2^n}}$ is rational?

I have seen in the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2137685/how-to-find-sum-n-0-infty-frac122n) that the sum converges and it was also mentioned that this is called Kempner's number. [Another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583472/sum-of-infinite-series-1-1-2-1-4-1-16-cdots) mentions this under the name Fredholm number.

Comment: The number is also [transcendental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number) by [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number)

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2365746/prove-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac15n-converges-to-an-irration

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In base 2, it is not finite or recurring, so it is irrational.

Comment: Brilliant solution. I'll definitely keep this one in my arsenal.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this paper](https://www.physicsforums.com/attachments/a-theorem-on-irrationality-of-infinite-series-pdf.33129/), if
$$a_n-a_{n-1}^2+a_{n-1}-1>0$$
for all $n$ greater than some $N\in\mathbb{N}$, then
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_n}$$
is irrational. In your case,
$$a_n-a_{n-1}^2+a_{n-1}-1=2^{2^n}-(2^{2^{n-1}})^2+2^{2^{n-1}}-1=2^{2^{n-1}}-1$$
which is greater than $0$ for all $n\geq 0$. Thus,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{2^n}}$$
is irrational.